# Program packaged by pyinstaller crashes when running

Tags: pyqt5, pyinstaller

I tried to create a command line program with pyqt5, and used pyinstaller to package it. My packing command is: `pyinstaller --windowed --onefile main.py`

However, after entering the command and running, my program crashes

If I use `pyinstaller --windowed main.py` or `pyinstaller --onefile main.py` the program still works

Here is the code:

**main.py**

```py
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPushButton, QPlainTextEdit, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout

class MyApp(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.window_width, self.window_height = 1200, 1500
        self.setMinimumSize(self.window_width, self.window_height)

        self.setWindowTitle('Command Line App')
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.editorCommand = QPlainTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.editorCommand, 3)

        self.editorOutput = QPlainTextEdit()
        layout.addWidget(self.editorOutput, 7)

        buttonLayout = QHBoxLayout()
        layout.addLayout(buttonLayout)

        self.button_run = QPushButton('&Run Command', clicked=self.runCommand)
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.button_run)

        self.button_clear = QPushButton('&Clear', clicked=lambda: self.editorOutput.clear())
        buttonLayout.addWidget(self.button_clear)

        self.editorCommand.insertPlainText('dir')

    def runCommand(self):
        command_line = self.editorCommand.toPlainText().strip()
        p = os.popen(command_line)
        if p:
            self.editorOutput.clear()
            output = p.read()
            self.editorOutput.insertPlainText(output)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyleSheet('''
        QWidget {
            font-size: 30px;
        }
    ''')
    
    myApp = MyApp()
    myApp.show()

    try:
        sys.exit(app.exec_())
    except SystemExit:
        print('Closing Window...')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try runnning PyInstaller this way:

```
pyinstaller -F -w my_file.py
```